# Heroku + Django + Postgres, can't make migration to postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, heroku

I'm trying to put a django based app on Heroku with Docker.
I'm using one container for postgres and another one for my app locally. In production, I only push my app and use heroku postgres add-on.

Locally it works fine. But when I try to upload it to Heroku, my app *seems* able to connect to postgres database, but can't find any tables.
I have no idea where the problem is, except maybe **migrate** fail because of some restricted authorisation (but I didn't see any error outputs through the Heroku logs):

here my docker-compose:

```
web:
build: .
command: bash -c "python3 manage.py migrate && python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
volumes:
  - .:/code
ports:
  - "8000:8000"
depends_on:
  - db
```

And here the postgres conf:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'postgres',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'HOST': 'db',
    'PORT': 5432,
}
}
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

Here is my problem:

1) I can't connect directly to the heroku dyno because this is a lot of painful configuration and I didn't succeed (the documentation is a little blurry about how to achieve this)

2) I have no idea if the postgres is actually linked. 
All i did is put **db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)** as asked in the heroku documentation. All I get is a ProgrammingError at /
relation "wagtailcore_site" does not exist, so I'm assuming postgres is running but the tables missing.

Note that I'm only pushing my web image to heroku. Postgres is already available through an heroku addon.

My problem is that I have no idea why my web command: python3 manage.py migrate seems to produce nothing, and once again, this is painful to debug because of all that layers.

## edit

From my heroku logs, I've got this generated configuration for the database.

```
{'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 'NAME': 'dfoj555gqmetqk', 'USER': 'jspejdlnonepyj', 'HOST': 'ec2-54-235-240-126.compute-1.amazonaws.com', 'PORT': 5432 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 500}}
```

And from Django Traceback, I get the confirmation the DB is connected.

```
DATABASES   
    {'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
                 'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
                 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 500,
                 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
                 'HOST': 'ec2-54-235-240-126.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
                 'NAME': 'dfoj555gqmetqk',
                 'OPTIONS': {},
                 'PASSWORD': '********************',
                 'PORT': 5432,
                 'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                          'COLLATION': None,
                          'MIRROR': None,
                          'NAME': None},
                 'TIME_ZONE': None,
                 'USER': 'jspejdlnonepyj'}}
```

But then, how can I do my migration into this DB? Is that possible that when I put the migration rule in Docker, the DB is not existing at this moment?

Comment: Are you running `makemigrations` at any point?

Comment: No I forget to add makemigrations. But adding this command didn't change the result.

Comment: How are you running makemigrations? Are you committing the result to version control? And you'll need to be more specific about your deployment configuration, are you actually deploying using Docker?

Comment: Are you running `manage.py migrate` after heroku deployment? Try adding this to your Procfile: `release: python manage.py migrate`

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Yes I am using Docker. But heroku wraps it into his own CLI, and worst of all, I can't debug from there. My problem is that when I do the migrate command, I have no idea when it is done and what it outputs.

Comment: Have you considered not using docker?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hahaha, yes. This is what I have done. I deployed manually my app and now it works: I think the process of making a migration from docker is maybe not a good idea. Those conf are client dependant and Docker should not have to deal with that in the first place. The fact that I can't debug from heroku with the heroku:container command is why I give-up: my dyno was crashing without knowing why. Lot of waste of time.